# CodeIgniter Upload and Resize Problem

Tags: codeigniter, image-manipulation

I have spent days trying to make this work based on the examples in the documentation but I am missing something or I am just STUPID!

I have a CMS application where users upload an image for display in a very fixed layout. We do not want to limit the file size of the uploaded image but would rather "process" it after it arrives.

The image needs to be 615px wide but some of the images uploaded directly from digital cameras are 2500X2000 and bigger so this is CRITICAL.

I pieced together the code from the manual and the image is successfully being uploaded to a folder within the CMS app. However, the image is NOT being resized.

If I ever get it to re-size, my plan is to present the image to the user for cropping using jCrop (the final image HAS to be 615X275 and it probably has to be cropped for height after resizing) and then use codeigniter to FTP the image to their site's amenities folder using the original name.

I will appreciate any help in this matter!

Here's my code:

```
function do_feature_upload() {
        $imageName = $this->uri->segment(3);
        //echo $imageName;

        // Where the file is going to be placed
        $config['upload_path'] =  "./uploads/".$_SESSION['dbPropNumber'];
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '0';
        $config['file_name'] = $imageName.'.jpg';
        $config['overwrite'] = 'TRUE';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

            $error['propertyDropdown'] = $_SESSION['propertyDropdown'];
            $error['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
            $error['dbPropNumber'] = $_SESSION['dbPropNumber'];
            $error['propertyName'] = $this->content->getPropertyName($_SESSION['dbPropNumber']);

            $this->load->view('upload_AmenityImage', $error);
        } else {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();

            $origWidth = $image_data['image_width'];
            $origHeight = $image_data['image_height'];
            $newWidth = 615;
            $newHeight = $newWidth*$origHeight/$origWidth;

            $resize = array(
                'image_library'=>'gd2',
                'source_image'=>base_url().'uploads/'.$_SESSION['dbPropNumber'].'/'.$imageName.'.jpg',
                'new_image'=>base_url().'uploads/'.$_SESSION['dbPropNumber'].'/'.$imageName.'1.jpg',
                'create_thumb' => FALSE,
                'maintain_ratio'=>FALSE,
                'width'=>$newWidth,
                'height'=>$newHeight
            );

            $this->load->library('image_lib',$resize);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            $data['propertyDropdown'] = $_SESSION['propertyDropdown'];
            $data['username'] = $_SESSION['username'];
            $data['dbPropNumber'] = $_SESSION['dbPropNumber'];
            $data['propertyName'] = $this->content->getPropertyName($_SESSION['dbPropNumber']);

            //Present jCrop option after image is resized

            // FTP to final destination

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        } // end if
    } // end function
```

Comment: try to remove base_url() in resize function. If I'm correct paths (source_image and new_image) have to be relative not absolute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what's going wrong with your code, but here's a model function I wrote for resizing images to fit an exact target height **and** target width. Read through it and see if you can't figure out the solution.

`$this->prefix` is a property in my class that I use so I don't have to keep writing out the directory of the file. It looks like this:

`$this->prefix = FCPATH.'uploads'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;`

**Image resizer**

```
/**
 * Resizes an image to fit exact dimensions
 * 
 * @param string    filename
 * @param int      target_width
 * @param int      target_height
 * 
 * @return array('success' ? null : 'error')
 */
function resizeImageToDimensions($filename, $target_width=700, $target_height=399)
{
    $file_type = $this->getFileType($this->prefix.$filename);

    if (!$file_type || $file_type != 'image')
        return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"This file doesn't exist or isn't an image");

    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($this->prefix.$filename);
    $current_ratio = $width/$height;
    $target_ratio = $target_width/$target_height;
    $config['source_image'] = $this->prefix.$filename;

    if ($current_ratio > $target_ratio)
    {
        //resize first to height, maintain ratio
        $config['height'] = $target_height;
        $config['width'] = $target_height * $current_ratio;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
            return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"There was an error while resizing this image");

        //then crop off width
        $config['width'] = $target_width;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if ($this->image_lib->crop())
            return array('success'=>true);
        else
            return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"There was an error while cropping this image");
    }
    else if ($current_ratio < $target_ratio)
    {
        //resize first to width, maintain ratio
        $config['width'] = $target_width;
        $config['height'] = $target_width / $current_ratio;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if (!$this->image_lib->resize())
            return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"There was an error while resizing this image");

        //then crop off height
        $config['height'] = $target_height;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = false;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if ($this->image_lib->crop())
            return array('success'=>true);
        else
            return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"There was an error while cropping this image");
    }
    else {
        $config['width'] = $target_width;
        $config['height'] = $target_height;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

        if ($this->image_lib->resize())
            return array('success'=>true);
        else
            return array('success'=>false, 'error'=>"There was an error while resizing this image");
    }
}
```

Comment: so I should put this in the model and call it like this: $this->content->resizeImageToDimensions($image_data['$image_data['full_path'],'],$newWidth, $newHeight);

Comment: Something like that, except be sure that the image path is pointing in the right place (it might take a bit of tinkering to get it to work right). It's not really necessary to keep this in a model, per se, but it's the way I like to organize things (I typically take a holistic approach to MVC...anything dealing with data/file storing/manipulation goes in the model). There's no real reason why this couldn't just be its own library or an extension on the image_lib. Whatever works best for you. But yes, best to keep this out of the controller because in all cases you should have thin controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a few months back and sadly, I wasn't able to figure it out. I've posted the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224315/resize-not-working-using-image-manipulation-class) and in [CodeIgniter's forums](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160383/) but no one could help me.

I ended up using [timthumb](http://www.darrenhoyt.com/2008/04/02/timthumb-php-script-released/) script, which is great, but nowhere near ideal :(

So, if you're in a rush, I'd strongly recommend using timthumb. If you have some time to invest on it, I wish you the best and please, share!